# Which of the following statements regarding mapplets are correct and true in Informatica?

Tags: transformation, informatica, mapplets

```
Which of the following statements regarding mapplets are correct and true in Informatica ?
A. A mapplet can contain a target definition
B. A mapplet can contain a source definition as well as a source qualifier
C. A transformation can be active and passive at the same time.
D. A mapplet can contain a normalizer transformation
```

I came across this question while appearing for Informatica certification.

Comment: Did you check by creating a mapplet?

Comment: I can understand that a mapplet can contain a source definition as well as a source qualifier. We can't use normalizer tranformation in mapplet

Answer (score 0):

I can understand that a mapplet can contain a source definition as well as a source qualifier.

Comment: I had gone through multiple sites to search for mapplet. A mapplet can contain a series of transformation who output can be used by other transformation